# Flask web app getting error on Heroku but working on localhost

Tags: heroku, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a Flask web app that's running perfectly fine on localhost. When I deployed to Heroku, it was a successful build. However, when I opened the web app, there was an error. This was the log message:

```
2016-11-21T07:17:17.106395+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/routes.py", line 2, in <module>
2016-11-21T07:17:17.106395+00:00 app[web.1]:     from data import SearchBar, CourseData
2016-11-21T07:17:17.106395+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/data.py", line 1, in <module>
2016-11-21T07:17:17.106396+00:00 app[web.1]:     from flask_wtf import Form
2016-11-21T07:17:17.106396+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named flask_wtf
```

I have WTForms installed. I'm not sure why it's not running on Heroku, though it's running fine on localhost.

Comment: Perhaps you have WTForms installed "globally" in your localhost installation?
Is it listed in your requirements.txt ?

Comment: It wasn't, but then I added it there. Still not working :(

Comment: Use virtualenv on localhost (http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/), and get it working there first, to make sure you are not relying on any dependencies from your global python installation on localhost. Once you have it working on a virtualenv on localhost, push to Heroku.

Comment: Everything is working without relying on global packages. So the error is in somewhere else